# Nlog Config does not insert any Value in DB

Tags: web-config, nlog

my Nlog Config is:

```
  <commandText>
    insert into NLog_Error ([time_stamp],[level],[host],[type],[source],[logger],[message],[stacktrace],[allxml]) values(@time_stamp,@level,@host,@type,@source,@logger,@message,@stacktrace,@allxml);
  </commandText>

  <parameter name="@time_stamp" layout="${utc_date}" />
  <parameter name="@level" layout="${level}" />
  <parameter name="@host" layout="${machinename}" />
  <parameter name="@type" layout="${exception:format=type}" />
  <parameter name="@source" layout="${callsite:className=true:fileName=false:includeSourcePath=false:methodName=false}" />
  <parameter name="@logger" layout="${logger}" />
  <parameter name="@message" layout="${message}" />
  <parameter name="@stacktrace" layout="${exception:stacktrace}" />
  <parameter name="@allxml" layout="${web_variables}" />
```

but my log output in mssql is empty. do not insert any data

what?

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable the nlog internal error message. Maybe you can find some clues there:
http://nlog-project.org/wiki/Logging_is_not_working_-_how_to_troubleshoot_it%3F